# **Smooth** Vs **Regular** function.

Tags: functions, continuity, smooth-functions

What is the difference between a **smooth** and a **regular** function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Or in other way, can you please post both *definitions*?

Comment: Are you doing algebraic-varieties-stuff?

Comment: @Gae.S. Sorry but I didnt understand your question, can you explain more pls?

Comment: I am asking if this question on regular functions comes from a term you have found while studying algebraic varieties.

Comment: My question is because I think that a **smooth** function is a $C^k$ function with $k \ge 0$, but am not sure if this is true, or if the definition of a **regular** function is the same. So can you please feed me with some info. Many thanks.

Comment: These terms may be used in different ways by different authors.  So it will help to reveal what topic you are asking about.  Right-click on the tag [tag:smooth-functions] above to see what our tag information is regarding that term.

Comment: @GEdgar I am talking in **calculus**, about differentiable functions, or maybe in **measure theory**, when dealing with *integral of derivative as the derivative of integral*...

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular for various definitions of "regular function" and "regular map".

Comment: @GEdgar but what about **smooth** functions? Dont **regular** function, and between its various definitions, have a link with a **smooth** function? And what is the def. of a **smooth** function? Many thanks.